# Check if array is empty in Bash

Tags: bash

I have an array which gets filled with different error messages as my script runs.

I need a way to check if it is empty of not at the end of the script and take a specific action if it is.

I have already tried treating it like a normal VAR and using -z to check it, but that does not seem to work.  Is there a way to check if an array is empty or not in Bash?

Answer (score 260):

Supposing your array is `$errors`, just check to see if the count of elements is zero.

```
if [ ${#errors[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "No errors, hooray"
else
    echo "Oops, something went wrong..."
fi
```

Comment: Does not work with `set -u`: "unbound variable" - if the array is empty.

Comment: @Igor: Works for me in Bash 4.4. `set -u;` `foo=();`  `[ ${#foo[@]} -eq 0 ] && echo empty`.  If I `unset foo`, then it prints `foo: unbound variable`, but that's different: the array variable doesn't exist at all, rather than existing and being empty.

Comment: Also tested in Bash 3.2 (OSX) when using `set -u` - as long as you declared your variable first, this works perfectly.

Comment: this one is more compatible for most shells, but found this arithmetic way also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65957757/1091853

Answer (score 60):

I generally use arithmetic expansion in this case:

```
if (( ${#a[@]} )); then
    echo not empty
fi
```

Comment: Nice and clean!  I like it.  I also note that if the first element of the array is always nonempty, `(( ${#a} ))` (length of the first element) will work also.  However, that will fail on `a=('')`, whereas `(( ${#a[@]} ))` given in the answer will succeed.

Comment: It might have been so once, but I can't reproduce it. If `echo $BASH_VERSION && a=('') && (( ${#a[@]} )) && echo not empty || echo empty` happens to output "empty," fell free to tell your version.

Comment: @x-yuri it works for me: if I run that exact command, the output is `5.0.17(1)-release` / `not empty`

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can also write it as `(( ${#a[@]} != 0 ))` if you prefer to make the non-zero check explicit.

Comment: ok yeah, see that one here that @dimo414 mentioned  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65957757/1091853

Answer (score 12):

You can also consider the array as a simple variable. In that way, just using

```
if [ -z "$array" ]; then
    echo "Array empty"
else
    echo "Array non empty"
fi
```

or using the other side

```
if [ -n "$array" ]; then
    echo "Array non empty"
else
    echo "Array empty"
fi
```

The problem with that solution is that if an array is declared like this: `array=('' foo)`. These checks will report the array as empty, while it is clearly not. (thanks @musiphil!)

Using `[ -z "$array[@]" ]` is clearly not a solution neither. Not specifying curly brackets tries to interpret `$array` as a string (`[@]` is in that case a simple literal string) and is therefore always reported as false: "is the literal string `[@]` empty?" Clearly not.

Comment: `[ -z "$array" ]` or `[ -n "$array" ]` doesn't work. Try `array=('' foo); [ -z "$array" ] && echo empty`, and it will print `empty` even though `array` is clearly not empty.

Comment: `[[ -n "${array[*]}" ]]` interpolates the entire array as a string, which you check for non-zero length.  If you consider `array=("" "")` to be empty, rather than having two empty elements, this might be useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't think that works. The expression evaluates to a single space character, and `[[ -n " " ]]` is "true," which is a pity. Your comment is exactly what I _want_ to do.

Comment: @Michael: Crap, you're right.  It only works with a 1-element array of an empty string, not 2 elements.  I even checked older bash and it's still wrong there; like you say `set -x` shows how it expands.  I guess I didn't test that comment before posting. >.<  You can make it work by setting `IFS=''` (save/restore it around this statement), because `"${array[*]}"` expansion separates elements with the first character of IFS.  (Or space if unset).  But "*If IFS is null, the parameters are joined  without intervening separators.*" (docs for $* positional params, but I assume same for arrays).

Comment: @Michael: Added an answer that does this.

Comment: This answer is straight up wrong, why does it have 8 points? It believes the array is incorrectly empty for many different cases

Comment: this is only check if the first element is empty, not the array.

Comment: -1, please don't go around treating arrays like scalars, it's just going to confuse people (and will be wrong in all sorts of cases).

Answer (score 9):

I checked it with `bash-4.4.0`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
check() {
    if [[ ${array[@]} ]]; then
        echo not empty
    else
        echo empty
    fi
}
check   # empty
array=(a b c d)
check   # not empty
array=()
check   # empty
```

and `bash-4.1.5`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
check() {
    if [[ ${array[@]:+${array[@]}} ]]; then
        echo non-empty
    else
        echo empty
    fi
}
check   # empty
array=(a b c d)
check   # not empty
array=()
check   # empty
```

In the latter case you need the following construct:

```
${array[@]:+${array[@]}}
```

for it to not fail on empty or unset array. That's if you do `set -eu` like I usually do. This provides for more strict error checking. From [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being inverted with !. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.
>
> -u
>
> Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion. An error message will be written to the standard error, and a non-interactive shell will exit.

If you don't need that, feel free to omit `:+${array[@]}` part.

Also do note, that it's essential to use `[[` operator here, with `[` you get:

```
$ cat 1.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
array=(a b c d)
if [ "${array[@]}" ]; then
    echo non-empty
else
    echo empty
fi

$ ./1.sh
_/1.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
empty
```

Comment: With `-u` you should actually use `${array[@]+"${array[@]}"}` cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361807/1237617

Comment: @JakubBochenski Which version of bash are you talking about? https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/d933972a2f1c42a49fc7999b8d5c50b9

Comment: The problem in the single brackets example is the `@`, surely. You could use `*` array expansion like `[ "${array[*]}" ]`, could you not? Still, `[[` also works fine.

The behaviour of both of these for an array with multiple empty strings is a little surprising. Both `[ ${#array[*]} ]` and `[[ "${array[@]}" ]]` are false for `array=()` and `array=('')` but true for `array=('' '')` (two or more empty strings). If you wanted one or more empty strings to all give true, you could use `[ ${#array[@]} -gt 0 ]`. If you wanted them all false, you could maybe `//` them out.

Comment: @eisd I could use `[ "${array[*]}" ]`, but if I were to run into such expression, it would be harder for me to understand what it does. Since `[...]` operates in terms of strings on the result of interpolation. As opposed to `[[...]]`, which can be aware of what was interpolated. That is, it can know that it was passed an array. `[[ ${array[@]} ]]` reads to me as "check if array is non-empty", while `[ "${array[*]}" ]` as "check if result of interpolation of all array elements is a non-empty string".

Comment: ...As for behavior with two empty strings it is not at all surprising to me. What is surprising is the behavior with one empty string. But arguably reasonable. Regarding `[ ${#array[*]} ]`, you probably meant `[ "${array[*]}" ]`, since the former is true for any number of elements. Because number of elements is always non-empty string. Regarding the latter with two elements, the expression inside brackets expands to `' '` which is non-empty string. As for `[[ ${array[@]} ]]`, they just think (and rightly so) that any array of two elements is non-empty.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to detect an array with empty *elements*, like `arr=("" "")`** as empty, same as `arr=()`

You can paste all the elements together and check if the result is zero-length.  (Building a flattened copy of the array contents is not ideal for performance if the array could be very large.  But hopefully you aren't using bash for programs like that...)

But `"${arr[*]}"` expands with elements separated by the first character of `IFS`.  So you need to save/restore IFS and do `IFS=''` to make this work, or else check that the string length == # of array elements - 1.  (An array of `n` elements has `n-1` separators).  To deal with that off-by-one, it's easiest to pad the concatenation by 1

```
arr=("" "")

## Assuming default non-empty IFS
## TODO: also check for ${#arr[@]} -eq 0
concat="${arr[*]} "      # n-1 separators + 1 space + array elements
[[ "${#concat}" -ne "${#arr[@]}" ]]  && echo not empty array || echo empty array
```

test case with `set -x`

```
### a non-empty element
$ arr=("" "x")
  + arr=("" "x")
$ concat="${arr[*]} ";  [[ "${#concat}" -ne "${#arr[@]}" ]] && echo not empty array || echo empty array
  + concat=' x '
  + [[ 3 -ne 2 ]]
  + echo not empty array
not empty array

### 2 empty elements
$ arr=("" "")
  + arr=("" "")
$ concat="${arr[*]} ";  [[ "${#concat}" -ne "${#arr[@]}" ]] && echo not empty array || echo empty array
  + concat='  '
  + [[ 2 -ne 2 ]]
  + echo empty array
empty array
```

**Unfortunately this fails for `arr=()` : `[[ 1 -ne 0 ]]`.**  So you'd need to check for actually empty arrays first separately.

---

**Or with `IFS=''`**.  Probably you'd want to save/restore IFS instead of using a subshell, because you can't get a result out of a subshell easily.

```
# inside a () subshell so we don't modify our own IFS
(IFS='' ; [[ -n "${arr[*]}" ]] && echo not empty array || echo empty array)
```

example:

```
$ arr=("" "")
$ (IFS='' ; [[ -n "${arr[*]}" ]] && echo not empty array || echo empty array)
   + IFS=
   + [[ -n '' ]]
   + echo empty array
empty array
```

*does* work with `arr=()` - it's still just the empty string.

Comment: I upvoted, but I've started using `[[ "${arr[*]}" = *[![:space:]]* ]]`, since I can count on at least one non-WS character.

Comment: @Michael: yup, that's a good option if you don't need to reject `arr=(" ")`.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use double brackets:

```
if [[ ! ${array[@]} ]]
then
    echo "Array is empty"
else
    echo "Array is not empty"
fi
```

> Double Brackets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669452/is-preferable-over-in-bash

Edited in order to work as expected

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the [second Answer](https://serverfault.com/a/477506) was not enough because there could be whitespaces. I came along with:

```sh
if [ "$(echo -ne ${opts} | wc -m)" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "No options"
else
  echo "Options found"
fi
```

Comment: `echo | wc` seems needlessly inefficient compared using shell built-ins.

Comment: Not sure if I understand @PeterCordes, can I modify the second answers' `[ ${#errors[@]} -eq 0 ];` in a way to work around the whitespace problem? I'd also prefer the built-in.

Comment: How exactly does whitespace cause a problem?  `$#` expands to a number, and works fine even after `opts+=("")`.  e.g. `unset opts;` `opts+=("");opts+=(" "); echo "${#opts[@]}"` and I get `2`.  Can you show an example of something that doesn't work?

Comment: It's long time ago. IIRC the originating source always printed at least "". Thus, for opts="" or opts=("") I needed 0, not 1, ignoring the empty newline or empty string.

Comment: Ok, so you need to treat `opts=("")` the same as `opts=()`?  That's not an empty array, but you could check for empty array or empty first element with `opts=("");`  `[[ "${#opts[@]}" -eq 0 || -z "$opts" ]] && echo empty`.  Note that your current answer says "no options" for `opts=("" "-foo")`, which is totally bogus, and this reproduces that behaviour.  **You could `[[ -z "${opts[*]}" ]]` I guess, to interpolate all the array elements into a flat string, which `-z` checks for non-zero length.**  If checking the first element is sufficient, `-z "$opts"` works.

Comment: Just realized there was already an answer that did the same bogus check as this (but without `echo | wc`): https://serverfault.com/questions/477503/check-if-array-is-empty-in-bash/700936#700936.

Comment: Oh hmm, I guess if you want to ignore whitespace as well as empty strings, you have to find a way to expand your variable in a way that lets the shell eat whitespace without causing a syntax error.  An `echo` command line makes some sense, but you could probably do it by checking "${opts[*]}"` against a glob or regex that matches non-whitespace.  (Inside a `[[  ]]`).

Comment: Update: `"${opts[*]}"` expands with array elements separated by the first character of `$IFS`.  So **I'd need `IFS=''`** (the empty string) to paste them together without space separators, and make `"${opts[*]}"` zero-length even if the array has multiple empty elements.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I cannot comment yet - Regarding @Nick Tsai - I didn't work for me but the following:

```
if [[ ! ${arrayName[*]} ]]; then ...
if [[ ! ${arrayOne[*]} && ! ${arrayTwo[*]} ]]; then ...
```

spacing is important for this to work!

Answer (score -1):

You could also benefit from jq if you got it installed on your system:

```sh
if [[ $(echo $array | jq -r 'length') -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "Array is empty"
else
    echo "Array is not empty"
fi
```